# IIS Issue with VS2010 and VS2013 Web App Configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, visual-studio-2013

When I'm trying to configure my web application on IIS7.5 under Window7 it is showing this error as below:

```
Bad Request - Request Too Long

HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.
```

I've been tried to configure ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET 4.5 from VS2010 and VS2013 but I could not start the
application, advice

with specified port

```
http://localhost:8001/Home.aspx
```

Comment: What request does this happen on? A GET with no query string?

Comment: Yes without query string #john Saunders

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The content of the following link was for me very helpful and it worked as well after this changes:
http://www.developermemo.com/3068063/